# how to sum range in case of merged cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have got the following situation

[image]

which are three cells in a row (1800,323,900) and one merged cell (28). I have got a whole column like this. So how can I use vba to add the sum of each of the values in the left column summed with 28 and paste each of these in corresponding right-most column. So the desired output is:

[image]

I tried using range.formula but it does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merged cell is referenced using the first row number that is merged. So if cells B1 to B3 are merged, then the merged cell is always B1.

If we assume that your data is in column A, the merged cell starting in column B row 1, and the formulae you want inserted in column C, then you can use the following code:

```
Sub Sum_Merged()

Range("C1:C" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=RC[-2]+R1C2"

End Sub
```

If any of those assumption are wrong, then just replace the above columns/rows with the relevant letters and numbers.